# Error when I try to claim my url (Facebook Instant Articles)

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I am trying to claim my url in order to upload the initial articles for review through the [wordpress plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/fb-instant-articles/). I have everything setup with the plugin but when I click "Submit for review" I get a "Permissions Error Toast":

[image]

The plugin does have a low rating so maybe this is one of the things that don't work or it could have to do with the app that I'm using is one I ust created and doesn't have permissions to manage instant articles (didn't want to start down that road unless I absolutely have to).

As a work around, I can just submit the initial 5 articles through the Facebook interface manually with the output from the wordpress plugin. When I try to create an article I get this error:

[image]

Ok.. so I have to claim my url. After a while of researching I found the place to claim the url. I have followed the instructions and added `<meta property="fb:pages" content="1xxxxx0" />` in the `<head/>` of my site and I have verified that it is there. No matter what I put as my url I get this error:

[image]

I thought that the issue could have done with our redirect to `https` so I tried our staging server which doesn't redirect to https and I get the same issue. On the homepage there is another redirect that will redirect the user to their regions local homepage which could cause it to mess up? The error is too vague for me to debug it myself without speculating and all the answers that I've found tell you to put the meta in the head of the site which isn't very helpful since its already there.

Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: That is a debugger for sharing content, not for instant articles?

Comment: It will nevertheless tell you whether Facebook finds the expected meta data when reading your URL, or not, and what errors there are.

Answer (score 1):

The issue had to do with the location redirect that we do with new visitors. The solve was to not do the redirect when its Facebook requesting the page.

```
strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'facebookexternalhit') === FALSE
```